# Sheasa Nisim ALL 8 nights?

Tags: halacha, minhag, chanuka

Why do we say SheAsa Nisim all 8 nights? Shouldn't we only say it one night, the first?

Comment: Why not say it all 8 nights? We say it by the night and day time megillah reading!

Comment: We'll that's the same reason we say birkot haTorah every day because it's a new day. However, here it was ONE miracle.

Comment: I don't follow... Each night lighting candles is a new day too.

Comment: Tell you the truth, this is a question on a Halacha sheet for someone I know for school... I don't like the question either but we need the answer so he can study.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain why you think it should be only one night.

Comment: I don't think it should only be one though. It's a question on a Halacha sheet. I don't even understand the logic.

Comment: @H'Gabriel **|** Seems to me that this is the same as "Why do we light candles for 8 nights if the miracle was only on the first?"  In which case, any of the many answers to that question would apply here.

Comment: Why post a question that you don't understand the point of?

Comment: Because maybe someone will understand the logic. I don't understand the logic.

Comment: If someone understands and inserts logic into the question, I'll consider re-opening it.

Comment: I understand your closing of the question and I respect it. Tell you truth I was thinking of deleting it myself.

Comment: @IsaacMoses The hava amina to only say sheasah nissim only on the first night is a hava amina in the gemara on shabbat 23a. see my answer below for the gemara's response.

Comment: though I can't say i see that much value in the question...

Comment: @double aa I don't either it's a Halacha sheet for a child in 4th grade...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gemara gives an answer in [Shabbat 23a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=23&format=pdf)

> נס כל יומי איתיה.

which rashi there interprets to mean that the miracle continued happening the entire 8 days so we say the bracha over the course of the entire 8 days.