# Where's the eighth miracle?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia, miracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beis Yosef Question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/beis-yosef-question)

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12393/sheasa-nisim-all-8-nights).

If the sealed jug of oil that they found had enough to light the Menorah for one day, then there were only seven miraculous days of oil-burning. Why do we celebrate Chanukah for eight days (and light eight lights) if there were only seven miracles?